Tensorflow.js custom trained model issues
I created my own tensorflow model to detect only one object (trucks) in images. The model works perfectly in Python, it's a saved model (saved_model.pb), and I need to use it in the browser with Tensorflow.js. In order to do this, I converted my model (saved_model.pb) to model.json with all their bin files.
So, in javascript, I load my model, also one image with trucks for testing, when I try to detect objects in it and draw the boxes. I get like a lot of predictions, and 100 classes (when there's only one), and it just doesn't work. I tried ChatGPT, forums, and I just can't.
JS:
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    document.getElementById('detect-objects-btn').addEventListener('click', detectObjects);
    loadModel();

    let model;
    // Cargar el modelo MobileNet v2
    async function loadModel() {
        // Cargar el modelo de detección de objetos (COCO, por ejemplo)
        model = await tf.loadGraphModel('/wp-content/plugins/truck-detector-dashboard/model/model.json');
        console.log("Modelo cargado exitosamente.");
        document.getElementById('detect-objects-btn').disabled = false; // Activar el botón
    }

    async function detectObjects() {
        const img = document.getElementById('test-image');
        canvas.width = img.width;  // Ajustar el canvas al tamaño de la imagen
        canvas.height = img.height;

        const imgTensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(img);
        const resizedImage = tf.image.resizeBilinear(imgTensor, [640, 640]);
        const imageInt32 = tf.cast(resizedImage, 'int32');
        const inputTensor = imageInt32.expandDims(0);

        // Realizar predicción
        const predictions = await model.executeAsync(inputTensor);

        // Asumir que las predicciones son en el formato [boxes, scores]
        const [boxes, scores] = predictions;
        const boxesArray = await boxes.array();
        const scoresArray = await scores.array();
        console.log(predictions)
        console.log(scoresArray)
        console.log(boxesArray)

        // Liberar memoria de los tensores
        tf.dispose([imgTensor, resizedImage, inputTensor, boxes, scores]);

        // Dibujar la imagen en el canvas
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        // Dibujar las cajas delimitadoras con un umbral de confianza
        const threshold = 0.5; // Umbral de confianza
        const widthRatio = img.width / 640;
        const heightRatio = img.height / 640;

        boxesArray.forEach((box, i) => {
            const score = scoresArray[i];
            if (score > threshold) {
                // Box format assumed to be [ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax]
                const [ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax] = box;

                // Convert to original image size
                const x = xmin * widthRatio;
                const y = ymin * heightRatio;
                const width = (xmax - xmin) * widthRatio;
                const height = (ymax - ymin) * heightRatio;

                // Draw the bounding box
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(x, y, width, height);
                ctx.lineWidth = 2;
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        });
    }
});




HTML container:
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <img id="test-image" src="/wp-content/plugins/truck-detector-dashboard/images/truck_1.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous" style="width: 500px;">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    <button id="detect-objects-btn" disabled>Detectar objetos</button>

enter image description here
enter image description here
The only solution I see is trying to use Python here as backend somehow (because it works perfectly with Python and the saved_model.pb), because even after the conversion with tensorflow.js, it just doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?
